# Can't reset sa password

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to drop and recreate sa account to reset the password.

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = N'sa')
DROP LOGIN [sa]
GO
```

I am getting an error

```
Cannot use the special principal 'sa'.
```

also when I try to reset sa password in SSMS, I am getting an error `Cannot alter the login 'sa' because it does not exist or you don't have permission. Error: 15151`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sp_password NULL,'new_password','sa'
go
```